# Google Maps Static Custom Icon

Tags: php, google-maps

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.442797,-80.880361&zoom=12&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://*****.com/images/icon-marker.png|35.442797,-80.880361&sensor=false
```

For some reason, I am not seeing my custom icon. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your icon is too large.  From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons):

The icon parameter must be specified using a URL (which should be URL-encoded). You may use any valid URL of your choosing, or a URL-shortening service such as http://bit.ly or http://tinyurl.com. Most URL-shortening services have the advantage of automatically encoding URLs. Icons are limited to sizes of **4096 pixels (64x64 for square images)**, and the Static Maps service allows up to five unique custom icons per request. Note that each of these unique icons may be used multiple times within the static map.

Your image is 80x52 (4,160 pixels).